# How to make GitHub Actions job execute even if the previous has failed?

Tags: github-actions

[image: This is my workflow]

I want to make it so that quality gate summary job executes when the previous have failed. Also `continue-on-error: true` does not work in my case because at the end it will show that the pipeline has been executed successfully even when it's not. This is the code for that :

```
  quality-gate-summary:
    name: Quality Gate Summary
    runs-on: self-hosted
    needs: [ article-sonarqube, farmer-sonarqube, transport-sonarqube ]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Write Combined Commit Message
        if: always() && (needs.article-sonarqube.outputs.quality-gate-status == 'FAILED' || needs.farmer-sonarqube.outputs.quality-gate-status == 'FAILED' || needs.transport-sonarqube.outputs.quality-gate-status == 'FAILED')
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          FAILED_MODULES=""
          if [ "${{ needs.article-sonarqube.outputs.quality-gate-status }}" == "FAILED" ]; then
            FAILED_MODULES="$FAILED_MODULES\n- Article Module"
          fi
          if [ "${{ needs.farmer-sonarqube.outputs.quality-gate-status }}" == "FAILED" ]; then
            FAILED_MODULES="$FAILED_MODULES\n- Farmer Module"
          fi
          if [ "${{ needs.transport-sonarqube.outputs.quality-gate-status }}" == "FAILED" ]; then
            FAILED_MODULES="$FAILED_MODULES\n- Transport Module"
          fi
          COMMENT_BODY="SonarQube Quality Gate failed for the following modules:$FAILED_MODULES"
          echo "COMMENT_BODY<<EOF" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "$COMMENT_BODY" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "EOF" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Create commit comment
        if: env.COMMENT_BODY != ''
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          script: |
            github.rest.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: process.env.COMMENT_BODY
            })
      - name: Fail workflow
        if: always() && (needs.article-sonarqube.outputs.quality-gate-status == 'FAILED' || needs.farmer-sonarqube.outputs.quality-gate-status == 'FAILED' || needs.transport-sonarqube.outputs.quality-gate-status == 'FAILED')
        run: |
          echo "One or more quality gates failed. Failing the workflow."
          exit 1
```